# Probability that each r-1 tuple is contained in at least one edge in a r-uniform hypergraph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $n\ge r\ge 2$ and $p\in [0,1]$. Consider the random $r$-uniform hypergraph $H_r(n,p)$ on $n$ vertices, in which each $r$-tuple forms an edge with probability $p$ independently. Let $A$ be the event that each $(r-1)$-tuple is contained in at least one edge. For $\epsilon>0$, show that:
>   $$\mathbb P(A)\rightarrow 
>  \begin{cases} 
>       0 & \text{if } p\leq (1-\epsilon)\frac{(r-1)\ln{n}}{n} \\
>       1 & \text{if } p\geq (1+\epsilon)\frac{(r-1)\ln{n}}{n}
>    \end{cases}$$
>   as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Here is what I tried so far. For each $(r-1)$-tuple $t$, create a random variable $X_t$ which equals $0$ if $t$ is contained in some $r$-tuple and $1$ otherwise.
$\mathbb E(X_t)=\mathbb P(X_t=1)=(1-p)^{n-r+1}$, as there are $n-r+1$ such $r$-tuples containing $t$. Now $\displaystyle \mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(\sum X_t=0)\ge 1-\sum_t P(X_t=1)=1-\binom{n}{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r+1}$. Now if $p\geq (1+\epsilon)\frac{(r-1)\ln{n}}{n}$, then clearly
$$\binom{n}{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r+1}\le \binom{n}{r-1}\left(1-(1+\epsilon)\frac{(r-1)\ln{n}}{n}\right)^{n-r+1} \rightarrow 0$$
by applying $\binom{n}{r-1}\le \left(\frac{en}{r-1}\right)^{r-1}$ and $1+x\le e^x$ for the second factor. So this gives the second case, however I don't know what to do about the first one.